# Google Cloud Function not able to (write to)/(create a) bigquery table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Google Cloud Function is throwing following error despite the fact that service account which is used in Cloud Scheduler and the account which is trying to invoke the cloud function both have the listed permission granted.

This is the cloud scheduler configuration:

[image]

and permissions allocated to this account.

[image]

This is the cloud functions log output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Function uses a service account to run its code. This service account (SA) can be different from the one used and you are showing in Cloud Scheduler. (By default Cloud Function uses App Engine default SA as you can see in the screenshot below)

So start by checking which SA are you using and which roles it has.

By the way if you access the log entry in Google Cloud Logging and expand all nested fields, you can find which identity is missing which permissions through the `authenticationInfo` and `authorizationInfo` fields

[image]

Comment: This turned out to be the case and now its resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The service account (the identity that is calling BigQuery) does not have the permission **bigquery.jobs.create**.

Add the IAM role **roles/bigquery.jobUser** aka **BigQuery Job User** to the service account.

It is not clear from your question, but it appears that you are calling Cloud Functions. Cloud Functions then calls BigQuery. The service account assigned to Cloud Functions requires the IAM permission.

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control)